# How do I compile "styleName" into two separate classes?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

So, I use CSS Modules webpack loader:

`css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]_[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]`

I want to compile each `styleName` property to not only the generic class name usually generated but also to another simpler class.

for example: the code

`<div styleName="CLASS-NAME" />`

now compiles to

`<div class="path_filename_CLASS-NAME_12345" />`

and i want it to compile to

`<div class="_CLASS-NAME  path_filename_CLASS-NAME_12345" />`

Comment: Why would you want something like this? What's the purpose?

Comment: testing. targeting items using their class names. there is a complex outside testing system in the company i work with where the qa team is using class names to target elements.